# How to Install Ammyy Admin in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I want to install ammyy admin in UBUNTU 13.04. 
Someone help me how to install.

Answer (score 1):

13.04 has gone end of life a while back so it will be better to upgrade to a supported release.

Besides that: they only supply [Windows installers](http://www.ammyy.com/en/downloads.html). You can [ask them](http://www.ammyy.com/en/support.html) for a debian installer. But I would suggest looking for alternatives (like Teamviewer, TightVNC). Ammyy is not going to be for us.